# Javascript into one cell of Table instead of whole page

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Hi so i think this might be a very simple question but I cant find the answer anywhere.

I have a javascript function which pulls the information from my database and I am trying to get it to be up into one cell of a table but it is outputting to the whole page

[image: what the system is outputting]

The HTML

```
<tr>
<td class="tg-baqh" id='Emp1'></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" placeholder="enter shift" class="form-control" id='shiftInput'></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" placeholder="enter shift" class="form-control" id='shiftInput'></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" placeholder="enter shift" class="form-control"></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" placeholder="enter shift" class="form-control"></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" placeholder="enter shift" class="form-control"></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" placeholder="enter shift" class="form-control"></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" placeholder="enter shift" class="form-control"></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l">30/16</td>
```

The Javascript

```
     $(function Emp1(){

    // Get a database reference to our posts
    var employeeref = new Firebase("https://shiftsapp.firebaseio.com/employees/emp1");

    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
    employeeref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
     console.log(snapshot.val());
     document.write(snapshot.val());
     }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
      });

      });
```

Comment: That's what `document.write` does, it overwrites the document ?

Comment: You need to remove the images from here and post the code itself as part of your question.

Comment: @ManoDestra I have added the code and taken away the images.

Comment: @adeneo is there a function i can write that will just output to the table cell?

Comment: Sure, `$('#Emp1').html(snapshot.val())`

Comment: @adeneo your solution worked thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

The document.write() method replaces the whole document element, instead you should use [document.getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) or [document.getElementByClassName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) or some element selector method, then [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) or [append](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) the html only for that element. If you're using JQuery you can do something like :

```
var resutlHtml = "<div>test</div>"; //this is your html response
$('#tableId .tablecellclass').html(resultHtml);
```